# Redux Devtools does not work for any website

Tags: redux, next.js, devtools

[image]

The extension shows `(states are equal at all times )` i used to use it sometime back for react it worked. For my nextjs app its not working any fix ? I tried the Github Forms as well but many have the same problem .Also when i console log my state using `useSelector` it shows the data in the store

As usual i downloaded it from the chrome store as I have ubuntu now and then gave it the required perms like read URL's then tried to see my data in the redux store but it didnt work